# android parse JSON from url.. is not working?there is no response data

Tags: android, json, url

I followed [this](http://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-parse-json-data-in-android.html) to parse json from url

so here this is my json data

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": "login : success"
    }
}
```

I have respones data like

`"status": "login : success"
"status": "Logout : success"
"status": "Invalid User"`

only there kind there is no additonal data

for that I am Using

```
    if (json_data != null) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject get = new JSONObject(json_data);

                        JSONObject response = get.getJSONObject("response");

                        String status = response.getString("status");

                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\tStatus:+ status");
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

But I am not getting any repose.. weather problem with url function or This program is deprecated
If i type url in browser I am getting data..

**Update:**
My problem is that url is not reading.. if it is done I will see logs in my data base... and there is not response data.. as output..

I got error as `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host` in blue color.. but no output

any one please help me....

Comment: did you checked json_data?? its containting the data??

Comment: no ! actually i am initiating it as a string... can you suggest me by seeing my json data.. what is wrong

Comment: then check that after URL connection you are getting response or not.. and your this piece of code is right

Comment: every thing is right I followed that link.. I dont know where is the problem... can you suggest me some examples for my basic json output

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/  it is good for the understanding flow also.

Comment: I need to Show Only one output not in list view... its basic...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97054/discussion-between-aashvi-and-dont-be-negative).

Comment: have you given permission currectly? means inside <menifest> tag not in <appication> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Problem with `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host`

for this We need to change `hostname` with `IPaddress`

and also added new permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

along with internet permission

Because In some locations its necessary to add this permission especially VPN enabled places...

thanks to all..

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks file as per yout snippet!

**ReCheck  in manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```